# change default saving location in "make a copy" of a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

Im sure you know the option, that, if you click on a link of a GOogle Doc, you can adjust the link with
/copy, and each time you open the document, you have the option to click on "Make a copy" and 
a copy of the original file (Doc, sheet...) gets created and saved on "My drive" per default.

My question now is, can I somehow change this default path, where the files gets saved?
Like, can i say, save it per default in Google Drive folder xy, or can I even say, that
he shall ask in which of my Drive folder, the copy shall get saved?

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0):

Try using `makeCopy(name, destination)`.

> `makeCopy(name, destination)`
>
> - Creates a copy of the file in the destination directory and names it with the name provided.

```
function myFunction() {
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Sample Document');
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();

var copyFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID')
file.makeCopy('Sample Document Copy',copyFolder)

}
}
```

## Note:

The folder must be selected using folderID not byName( **based on experience and the tutorial example**)

Valuable Sources:

- [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [tutorial](http://alicekeeler.com/2015/03/17/google-apps-script-you-can-code-part-3/) - [How to use the makeCopy(name, destination) function](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/H1xLZZxwMTE/XH3mgA6LfRYJ) (This is very useful!)

Hope it helps.